# how to check idlemonitor in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

i have some problem when using javafx to check idle from user.i'm using javafx 8. i have main fxml file, that i called test.fxml. this file code is looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="7.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="191.0" layoutY="103.0" text="Test" />
            <TextField layoutX="263.0" layoutY="99.0" />
            <Button layoutX="263.0" layoutY="151.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="PROCES" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

if user getting idle like 30s for example, then user will bring to another fxml file. this code looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="7.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="191.0" layoutY="103.0" prefHeight="76.0" prefWidth="177.0" text="SORRY, YOU ARE IN IDLE TIME" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

thank you...

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX 2 User Idle Detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162374/javafx-2-user-idle-detection)

Comment: i think it`s different with fxml implementation