# Detect Idle State - JavaFX Application with Multiple Stages

Tags: javafx-8

I found the following idle question: [JavaFX 2 User Idle Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162374/javafx-2-user-idle-detection) however, I would like to create a global idle detection regardless of scene or stage.

Is there a way to check for idle on the FX Application as a whole, so that I can close it?

For example, I have a task window, which launches secondary stages, so if the user is working on one of those stages, I don't want the idle on the task window to fire.

The only examples I have seen are either scene or stage related.

For example:

MainWindow ->opens Window 1

MainWindow ->opens Window 2

MainWindow and Window 1 are idle while user interacts with Window 2 - idle should not fire.

However MainWindow, Window 1 and Window 2 are ALL idle, then it should.

Thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the solution you linked work? Just call `register(...)` once for each window, passing the scene each time?

Comment: We will have several dozen windows - each may be active, so Idle on one doesn't mean idle on the application.

Comment: I mean you use the same `IdleMonitor` instance and register all the scenes with it. Then "not idle" on any scene will reset the (single) timer.

Comment: I guess my concern here is having to replicate this code, and have developers remember to do it, rather than handle it right at login once for the entire application.

Comment: There are a number of solutions for that. E.g. write a utility method that creates stages for you, or have a stage subclass. These can observe the scene property and register/unregister it with a (singleton) `IdleMonitor`. I suspect in an application with "several dozen" windows there is other common functionality you need anyway.